# loop through a list of values / access different level of xsl hierarchy

Tags: xslt-1.0

I'm trying to loop through a list of values used as parameters, and get some other values from a different level of the hierarchy of my xml file. I wrote an example which I hope highlight the problem in a pertinent way.

constraints: I must use xslt 1.0 (xalan I believe), but I may be able to use exsl extensions if needed.

I have a list of packages, each of them containing a list of object's.

problem: the object description is not held in the  but at another place higher in the hierarchy.

so i want first to get a list of packages that I will store in a variable.

then in a second step getting the id of the objects in /root/packagelist/package[@id=$vid]/objectlist/object

then in a third step, process each of this trades by calling some xslt rules written somewhere else, that will need the object id as parameter.

just began using xslt, but as far as I understand, xsl for loops don't answer this, and should be avoided in any case (not trying to start a debate, just to follow best practises, which I'm unfamiliar with).
Also I read that some solved a similar issue using node-set, but could not figure out how.

would be grateful for any help or pointers to solve this issue.

Regards,

the input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <objectlist>
    <object id="1">
      <type>ok</type>
      <value>this is object 1</value>
    </object>
    <object id="3">
      <type>ko</type>
      <value>this is object 3</value>
    </object>
    <object id="2">
      <type>ok</type>
      <value>this is object 2</value>
    </object>
    <object id="4">
      <type>ko</type>
      <value>this is object 4</value>
    </object>
  </objectlist>
  <packagelist>
    <package id="a">
      <type>ok</type>
      <value>this is package a</value>
      <objectlist>
        <object id="1" />
        <object id="3" />
      </objectlist>
    </package>
    <package id="b">
      <type>ko</type>
      <value>this is package b</value>
      <objectlist>
        <object id="2">
        </object>
        <object id="4">
        </object>
      </objectlist>
    </package>
  </packagelist>
</root>
```

the xslt solution attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="package" mode="input01.package">
      <xsl:value-of select="@id" />      
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="object" mode="input01.package.objectid" >
      <xsl:value-of select="@id" />      
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="value" mode="input01.object" >
      <xsl:value-of select="." />         
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="object" mode="input01.object" >
      <xsl:apply-templates select="value" mode="input01.object" />      
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="package" mode="input01.package.objectid" >
      <xsl:apply-templates select="objectlist/object" mode="input01.package.objectid" />      
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/" mode="input01">


    <xsl:variable name="vPackageIDList" >
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/packagelist/package" mode="input01.package" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="vobjectIDList">   
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/packagelist/package" mode="input01.package.objectid" />    
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/objectlist/object" mode="input01.object" />

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/" >
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="input01" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

expected output of the tranformation would be, for example:

```
<myobjectlist>
    <myobject id="1" package="a">
        <type>ok</type>
        <value>this is object 1</value>
    </myobject>
    <myobject id="3" package="a">
        <type>ko</type>
        <value>this is object 3</value>
    </myobject>
    <myobject id="2" package="b">
        <type>ok</type>
        <value>this is object 2</value>
    </myobject>
    <myobject id="4" package="b">
        <type>ko</type>
        <value>this is object 4</value>
    </myobject>
</myobjectlist>
```

irrelevant to the problem, but if it can make testing easier, the c# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace XSLTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String filetest = "input01.xml";
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filetest, LoadOptions.None);
            XsltHandler xl = new XsltHandler();
            String xmlres = xl.Get(xdoc);
            Console.WriteLine("result=" + xmlres);
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Xsl;

namespace XSLTest
{
    class XsltHandler
    {
        internal string Get(XDocument aXDocument)
        {
            XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("input01.xslt");
            xslt.Load(reader);
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            XsltArgumentList arglist = new XsltArgumentList();
            xslt.Transform(aXDocument.CreateReader(), arglist, writer);

            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

edit:

Hi Michael,

Thanks a lot for answering, and for the code samples.
While trying to make things clear, I may have oversimplified the issue, sorry about that.
maybe the best way would be for me to describe this in pseudo code:

```
ObjectType getPackageType(PackageID pid)
{
    Package p = getPackage(pid);
    List<Object> objlist = getObjectList(p);
    for (int i = 1; i < objlist.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (objlist[i - 1].type != objlist[i])
            return new ObjectType("Error");
    }
    return objlist.type;
}
```

so the user would do something like this:

```
<xsl:template select="/" mode="input01">
    <xsl:with-param name="pPackageID" />
        <xsl:value select="'b'" />
    </xsl:with-param>
</xsl:template>
```

in the project I'm working on, I have many of templates of this form:

```
<xsl:template match="/" mode="type">
    <xsl:param name="objectID />
    <xsl:value-of select="/root/objectlist/object[@id=$objectID]/type" />
</xsl:template>
```

that extract various data from the the object and was planning using them.I hope this clarify the issue.
Not sure if I can use your answer to solve this, I don't see it, but I'll sleep over it...

Best,

ps: also regarding your question, no object can belong to two different packages. but I have no control over the structure of the xml input as it is often the case.

Comment: Could you please add the expected output of the transformation?

Comment: Hi Michael, I edited the question to add an example of desired output.

Comment: I am afraid you have lost me at this point. Are you trying to return a list of objects that are contained in a given package? If so, how will the given package's id be communicated to the stylesheet - will you send it as a parameter at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are making this much more complex than it needs to be. The result above can be achieved quite simply by:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="package" match="package" use="objectlist/object/@id" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <myobjectlist>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="objectlist/object"/>
    </myobjectlist>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="object">
    <myobject id="{@id}" package="{key('package', @id)/@id}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    </myobject>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or, if you prefer:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="package" match="package" use="objectlist/object/@id" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <myobjectlist>
        <xsl:for-each select="root/objectlist/object">
            <myobject id="{@id}" package="{key('package', @id)/@id}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
            </myobject>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </myobjectlist>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is assuming each object is in one package only. I am stressing this because your input schema is designed to support a situation that contradicts this assumption.

Comment: I added an edit at the end of the original question since it was too long. Best.